# no matching function for call to ‘IIRFilter<double>::IIRFilter()’ with templates in c++

Tags: c++, eigen

Here is my code. I don't know what details should be added... As you can see I'm using eigen. In the output it says that the error is in line with definition of Demodulator constructor.

So basically I have a template class Demodulator which could demodulate matrices of some type (double, float etc). And within the demodulator I'm using IIRFilter which also should be able to handle types of the demodulator.

Also filter should be able to filter not only the matrices but also the their blocks, hense all this code

```
template<typename Derived, typename DerivedB>
```

^^^^

```
        /*
         * Demodulator.h
         *
         *  Created on: May 23, 2014
         *      Author: ii
         */

        #ifndef DEMODULATOR_H_
        #define DEMODULATOR_H_

        #include <Eigen/Dense>
        #include <Eigen/Core>

        #include <iostream>
        #include "IIRFilter.h"

        using namespace std;
        using namespace Eigen;
        template <typename T>
        class Demodulator {
        public:
            Matrix<T, Dynamic, Dynamic> tempMatrix;
...
            IIRFilter<T> bandpassFilter;
            IIRFilter<T> highpassFilter;
            // Here is the error. In the line below.
            Demodulator(int rows, int columns) {

                tempMatrix = Matrix<T, Dynamic, Dynamic>(rows, columns);
                tempFrame = Matrix<T, 1, Dynamic>(1, rows);
                ...
                Matrix<T, 1, Dynamic> tempb1(7);
                tempb1 << 6.46597871e-01,   0.00000000e+00,  -1.93979361e+00,
                         1.66081634e-16,   1.93979361e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
                        -6.46597871e-01;

                bandpassFilter = IIRFilter<T>(tempa1, tempb1,  rows);
                Matrix<T, 1, Dynamic> tempb2(4);
                tempb2 << 0.97749153, -2.93247458,  2.93247458, -0.97749153;
                Matrix<T, 1, Dynamic> tempa2(3);
                tempa2 << -2.95447065,  2.90997187, -0.95548968;

                highpassFilter = IIRFilter<T>(tempa2, tempb2, rows);
...


            }
            ~Demodulator();

            void demodulateFrame(Matrix<T, Dynamic, Dynamic> &frame);
        };

        #endif /* DEMODULATOR_H_ */


    /*
     * IIRFilter.h
     *
     *  Created on: May 23, 2014
     *      Author: ii
     */

    #ifndef IIRFILTER_H_
    #define IIRFILTER_H_
    #include <Eigen/Dense>

    using namespace std;
    using namespace Eigen;
    template <typename T>
    class IIRFilter {
    public:

        Matrix<T, Dynamic, Dynamic> previousOutput;

        template<typename Derived, typename DerivedB>
        void filterRow(const MatrixBase<Derived>& input,  MatrixBase<DerivedB> const &  output, int row);

...


        IIRFilter(Matrix<T, 1, Dynamic> _alpha, Matrix<T, 1, Dynamic> _beta, int rows) {
            ...
        }
        ~IIRFilter();
    };




    #endif /* IIRFILTER_H_ */


    void testDemodulation() {
        MatrixXd input ...
        MatrixXd inputRow = input.row(0);

        Demodulator<double> demodulator(input.rows(), input.cols());
        demodulator.demodulateFrame(inputRow);
        cout << demodulator.outputFrame;

    }
```

Comment: Mark the line where the error is reported.

Comment: Where do you have the definitions of your template class methods?? Thoroughly check the link from the 1st comment!

Comment: I've read that before posting this question. But still I don't understand what is the problem. The definitions is in the header file and the cpp file is actually empty now.

Comment: I've marked the line with error

Comment: @user1685095 I can't spot one for e.g. `~Demodulator();`!

Answer (score 0):

You have to *initialize* your member variables. Since the class lacks default constructor, this initialisation must be explicit. There's a special syntax for that:

```
class Demodulator {

    Demodulator(int rows, int columns) 
           : bandpassFilter ( something ),                // <=== here
             highpassFilter ( something-else ) {          // <=== here
       // your code 
    }
```

Unfortunately these members require matrices as constructor arguments, and these matrices are not available yet.

You can either

- reorganise your code such that these matrices are available at this point, and remove `bandpassFilter =`,  `highpassFilter =` assignments, or
- add a default constructor to your IIRFilter class template just to enable initialisation by default, and keep the assignments